# Exporting .LAS file after using v.lidar.correction

Tags: point, grass-gis, lidar, database, las

## Question

I want to use the GRASS GIS LIDAR modules ([v.lidar.edgedetection](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/v.lidar.edgedetection.html), [v.lidar.growing](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/v.lidar.growing.html), and [v.lidar.correction](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/v.lidar.correction.html)) to classify points for LAS files. I'm very new to working with databases, and the tutorials on the wiki seem outdated.

The output of v.lidar.correction has no attribute table, but the new classification is stored in the category for Layer 2.

How do I export the correction to a .LAS file with all the original data (intensity, return number, source ID, etc.) included, but with the classifications included?

### Additional Info

I'm using GRASS GIS 7.8.8, installed with OSGeo4W.

To make things simpler, I'm using the sample dataset (nc_spm_08_grass7), and using the sample LIDAR data (lidar_raleigh_nc_spm_height_feet.las). I'm following the [workflow](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/v.lidar.edgedetection.html#complete-workflow) listed in v.lidar.edgedetection's helpfile.

These are the results when I query one of the points for correction@user1:

```
east, north: 638643.8660177002, 220301.83122000954
correction@user1: 
  Type: Point
  Id: 16041
  Point_height: 385.2
  Layer: 1
  Category: 1
correction@user1: 
  Type: Point
  Id: 16041
  Point_height: 385.2
  Layer: 3
  Category: 16041
correction@user1: 
  Type: Point
  Id: 16041
  Point_height: 385.2
  Layer: 4
  Category: 0
correction@user1: 
  Type: Point
  Id: 16041
  Point_height: 385.2
  Layer: 2
  Category: 1
```

From the helpfile:

> TERRAIN SINGLE PULSE (cat = 1, layer = 2)
> TERRAIN DOUBLE PULSE (cat = 2, layer = 2)
> OBJECT SINGLE PULSE (cat = 3, layer = 2)
> OBJECT DOUBLE PULSE (cat = 4, layer = 2)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to focus on your task and the problem encountered, without a list of later tasks.